# How to change the font color and family only to vertical center aligned yaxis label in Apache Echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

Thanks for the help in advance. I am using apache echarts for my react project. In it, I have a vertically center aligned y-axis label. I want to change its color and font family.The screenshot of my issue
[image]

Code I tried

```
yAxis: [
        {
            type: "value",
            name: "(x1000)",
            nameLocation: "middle",
            nameGap: 50,
            axisLabel: {
                textStyle: {
                    color: "red",
                },
            },
        },
    ],
```

but it changed the color of 0,0.2,0.4 etc values. I don't want that to change that but only the (x1000) label. Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this config:

```
yAxis: [
        {
            type: "value",
            name: "(x1000)",
            nameLocation: "middle",
            nameGap: 50,
            nameTextStyle: {
                color: "red",
                fontFamily: "sans-serif"
            },
        },
    ],
```